# Pythonanywhere Pillow install not working

Tags: django, python-3.4, pythonanywhere

I have loaded my django app onto Pythonanywhere and when running through my functions, I learned I cannot upload images through the Admin since I moved into production. I am getting this error:

```
Neither Pillow nor PIL could be imported: No module named 'Image'
```

Which from prior experience means Pillow isn't installed. So I opened a bash console and ran

```
pip3 install --user Pillow
```

and it said it installed correctly, and I **did** reload my app but it still doesn't work
 (same error). What went wrong?

Thanks in advance, Conner

Also, I did see this question on their forums: https://www.pythonanywhere.com/forums/topic/1247/

---

UPDATE:
Tried uninstalling Pillow and re-installing, then restarting web server. Still not working.

Comment: Which Python version are you using for the app?  pip3 defaults to Python 3.3, so if you're using 3.4 then you need to run pip3.4.

Comment: Wow! I can't believe I didn't know that. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: @cdipaolo Were you successful ?

Comment: @mascot6699 Yeah use 'pip3.4 install --user Pillow' if you're using Python 3.4

Comment: @cdipaolo actually i had the same problem once so asked if it was fixed. In my case it was python 2.7 and i had to use "pip install --use-wheel Pillow"